# unknown ssl protocol error in connection to repo.magento.com:443

Tags: curl, certificate, magento-2.0

I get the following error after downloading the `cacert.pem` file from `https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`,  and adding `curl.cainfo=C:/xampp/Apache/cacert.pem` in `php.ini`

[image]

how do i get rid of this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved by changing registry values: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL2.0\Client "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000(0)